# How to make Ranking using case by Partition in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ranking, rank

I need to do Ranking, if the value is negative, then sort it by Asc, if it is positive then sort it by Desc

```
select
    Itemcode,
    isnull(sum(ss.DiscQty * ss.Cost),0) DescCost,
    RANK()OVER(Partition by Itemcode order by 
        case when isnull(sum(ss.DiscQty * ss.Cost),0) < 0 THEN isnull(sum(ss.DiscrepancyQty * ss.Cost),0) END ASC,
        case when isnull(sum(ss.DiscQty * ss.Cost),0) > 0 THEN isnull(sum(ss.DiscQty * ss.Cost),0) END DESC
    ) RANKS
from
    ss
Group by
    ItemNo
```

Comment: Sample data with expected result will help

Comment: "it doesn't work" is *not* a good description. If you get unexpected results, explain what results you were expecting and how this doesn't match. If you get an *error message* (what I would expect), **tell us** what the error message says.

Comment: ST_ItemEntry table missing in query. Please provide all related with scope info.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the pattern you are after?
Have simplified the code to highlight what is happening

```
;WITH Example (n) AS
(
    SELECT 1    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3    UNION ALL
    SELECT -1   UNION ALL
    SELECT -2   UNION ALL
    SELECT -3   
)
SELECT   n
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ABS(n)-0 DESC)
FROM Example
ORDER BY n,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ABS(n)-0 DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the criteria dynamically. Do the following

```
SELECT
    Brand,
    ItemNo,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemNo ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN ISNULL(Disc, 0) > 0 THEN SUM(Quantity * Item.Cost) ELSE 0 END DESC,
        CASE WHEN ISNULL(ST_ItemEntry.Discrepancy, 0) < 0 THEN SUM(Quantity * Item.Cost) ELSE 0 END ASC
    ) AS [Rank]
FROM
    item
GROUP BY
    Brand,ItemNo
```